# OSX - Dyld Error Message: Library not loaded

Tags: macos

I have a .app file. When I double click to open it, I get an error :

**Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/CoreFactoryTestStation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFactoryTestStation
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/FixtureController.app/Contents/MacOS/FixtureController
  Reason: image not found**

I dont have the source code for the project, but I do have the missing framework CoreFactoryTestStation.framework with me. Where am I supposed to add this library. Should I need the source code of the project to fix this?

Comment: You just install framework in /Library/Frameworks/ directory and test it. If the app is built to search in that directory then it should work.

Comment: @DevaraGudda I dont have access to the app bundle, I only have the .app file with me.

Comment: If the framework is installed in right location then you don't need to build it again existing app bundle should work.Where you have installed CoreFactoryTestStation.framework?

Comment: The client sent over only the .app file. When i encountered this error, I asked him for the libraries and he sent it to me separately. So I have CoreFactoryTestStation.framework with me and I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Go to folder /Library/Frameworks/ in finder and paste CoreFactoryTestStation.framework, run your app. That should resolve the loader error.

Comment: Is this a programming question?  I.e. did you write the application?

Comment: The client provided the .app file, I need to get it running first to work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to folder /Library/Frameworks/ in finder and paste CoreFactoryTestStation.framework, run your app. That should resolve the loader error. If you dont find the Frameworks folder, do create one and paste your CoreFactoryTestStation.framework in that.

Comment: Thank you, there is no error after pasting the files.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Target > Build Phase > Link Binary With Libraries pane and add your framework there

Comment: I dont have the source code for the project. Can the library be added to the package contents without the source code?

Comment: @Abi Libraries are for this purpose only. if you have .framewrok file you can add it

Comment: without the source code, how will u choose the Target>Build Phase>Link Binaries option?